# How to convert comma seprated text field into separate lines

Tags: javascript

I am creating vehicle listing website, and I have Vehicle Option fields with lots of text in it separated by comma.
Here is the code

```
<div class="dvs-options">
Driver Airbag,Anti-Lock Brakes,Passenger Airbag,Alarm,Side AirbagCD Player,AM/FM Radio,AM/FM Stereo,DVD,CD Changer,Aftermarket Speaker,Hard Disc,Satellite RadioPower Windows,Rear Window Defroster,Tinted Glass,Rear Window WiperPower Door Locks,Alloy Wheels,Power Mirrors,Sunroof,Third Row Seats,Power Slide DoorNo Accident history,Maintenance Records Available,One Owner,New Tires,Non-Smoker,Fully Loaded,Performance Tires,Turbo,Upgraded Sound System,Custom Wheels,Repainted CarLeather Seats,Power Seats,Child Seat,Bucket Seat
</div>
```

I want to output the display content of this text field in line by line like:

Driver Airbag

Anti-Lock Brakes

Passenger Airbag

How to achieve this using CSS or javascript?

Comment: [HTML Lists](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp)?

Comment: _"...using CSS or javascript?"_ Why? Why not fix the source of the output?

Comment: @Andreas Sir, the client provides the data in this format.

Comment: This source are generate dynamic or is static? if is static simple use `<ul><li></li></ul>` else how you generate that?

Comment: Add all the text in each `p` this will display as line by line

Comment: Hello Friends, this is a screenshot of current output: https://i.imgur.com/VNJZr3G.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use  [.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) with JavaScript to get current `text` and once you have all data you need to use `.split(',')` to [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function to get text from comma line by line.

We can also use `trim()` to remove extra spaces except `,` before using split function.

`Split` will generate an array of each line. You can use [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to go through it to generate a list item.

In your `forEach` loop you will generate a [lists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) `ul` `li` and assing the data back to your original div `.dvs-options` [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) and get selecting the element by [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method

Run snippet below.

```js
//Get the current data
let getText = document.querySelector('.dvs-options').textContent.trim().split(',')

//Store data as list
let str = '<ul>'

//Use foreach to get all the text
getText.forEach(function(data) {
  str += '<li>' + data + '</li>';
});

str += '</ul>';

//Replace the innerHTML
document.querySelector(".dvs-options").innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div class="dvs-options">
  Driver Airbag,Anti-Lock Brakes,Passenger Airbag,Alarm,Side AirbagCD Player,AM/FM Radio,AM/FM Stereo,DVD,CD Changer,Aftermarket Speaker,Hard Disc,Satellite RadioPower Windows,Rear Window Defroster,Tinted Glass,Rear Window WiperPower Door Locks,Alloy Wheels,Power
  Mirrors,Sunroof,Third Row Seats,Power Slide DoorNo Accident history,Maintenance Records Available,One Owner,New Tires,Non-Smoker,Fully Loaded,Performance Tires,Turbo,Upgraded Sound System,Custom Wheels,Repainted CarLeather Seats,Power Seats,Child Seat,Bucket
  Seat
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest to `trim()` the `textContent` before using `split()`. On your current example you inherit the markup linebreaks, which you can see by adding `white-space: pre` to `li` or in the DevTools.

Comment: @Lain Would not make much of a difference. but added to my answer as per the suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would have been so much easier and practical if your client supplied the data through an API but since what you need is just a solution, try this.

```
let data = document.getElementsByClassName("dvs-options")[0].innerText; 
data = data.split(",");
```

This will give each vehicle option in a JS Object.
You can go through each using a loop and list it out.

**EDIT**

```
const element = document.getElementsByClassName("dvs-options")[0];
let data = element.innerText;
data = data.split(",").join("\r\n");
element.innerText = data;
```

Here is the full code. It retrieves everything from the div and puts back in the same div in order.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this via CSS alone - CSS doesn't allow you to break lines based on commas, only on blank spaces.

In order to convert the CSV into multiple lines I suggest a simple JavaScript with Regex for better performance, like:

```
var csv = document.getElementsByClassName("dvs-options")[0].innerHTML;

const regex = /\,/gm;
const subst = `</p><p>`;
const result = csv.replace(regex, subst);

document.getElementsByClassName("dvs-options")[0].innerHTML = '<p>'+result+'</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a **list**, it is enough to just change the `white-space` behaviour and replace **commas** with linebreaks `\n` after trimming the current `textContent`.

```js
//REM: Replace "," with Linebreaks "\n"
document.querySelectorAll('.dvs-options').forEach(function(item){
  item.textContent = item.textContent.trim().split(',').join('\n')
})
```

```css
.dvs-options{
  white-space: pre
}
```

```html
<div class="dvs-options">
Driver Airbag,Anti-Lock Brakes,Passenger Airbag,Alarm,Side AirbagCD Player,AM/FM Radio,AM/FM Stereo,DVD,CD Changer,Aftermarket Speaker,Hard Disc,Satellite RadioPower Windows,Rear Window Defroster,Tinted Glass,Rear Window WiperPower Door Locks,Alloy Wheels,Power Mirrors,Sunroof,Third Row Seats,Power Slide DoorNo Accident history,Maintenance Records Available,One Owner,New Tires,Non-Smoker,Fully Loaded,Performance Tires,Turbo,Upgraded Sound System,Custom Wheels,Repainted CarLeather Seats,Power Seats,Child Seat,Bucket Seat
</div>
```